# How to force account creation before commerce checkout is complete?

Tags: commerce

I currently have a one-page checkout that works great for anonymous users. After payment is complete, an account is created with the 'Create a new account for an anonymous order' checkout rule.

Now I need to add a subscription product to the site, and plan to use Commerce License and Commerce License Billing to sell a role. To handle recurring payments, I plan to use Commerce Card on File.

This introduces a problem because Card on File requires an authenticated user in order to save cards. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1553468

How can I create a user account before checkout finishes so that Card on File can properly save cards?

Ideally, there would be a custom checkout page that forces account registration as a first step in checkout, but only for users purchasing subscription products.

I don't allow visitors to register on the site at the moment (except via Commerce Checkout), and I'd rather not change that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following steps :

- create a custom checkout pane (see  [checkout_pane_example.module](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce_examples%21checkout_pane_example%21checkout_pane_example.module/DC) ) and embed the user register form in that pane:

  ```
  /**
   * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info().
   */
  function vts_register_commerce_checkout_pane_info() {
    $panes['register'] = array(
      'title' => t('Create an account'),
      'base' => 'vts_register_pane',
      'name' => t('NAME'),
      'page' => 'checkout',
      'weight' => -5,
    );
    return $panes;
  }
  /*
   * Add user_register_form to register pane
   */
  function vts_register_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) { 
    $pane_form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
    return $pane_form;
  }
  /*
   * Alter checkout form register pane
   */
  function vts_register_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    unset($form['register']['actions']); 
  }
  /**
   * checkout form submission callback.
   */
  function vts_register_pane_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
    $new_user = array(
      //dsm to find the correct $form_state['input'] for username here, because I have an altered user register form...
      'name' => $form_state['input']['field_name_first']['und'][0]['value'].'_'.$form_state['input']['field_name_last']['und'][0]['value'],
      'pass' => user_password(),
      'mail' => $form_state['input']['mail'],
      'init' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
      'status' => 1,
      'roles' => array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE),
    );
    if($GLOBALS['user']->uid == '0') {
      $user = user_save('', $new_user);
      //ASSIGN the current order to created user
      $order->uid = $user->uid;
      commerce_order_save($order);
      $GLOBALS['user'] = $user;
    }
    //check that you got a new user and the order was assigned to him
    dsm($user, 'user');
    dsm($order, 'order');
  }
  /**
   * Validation callback.
   */
  function vts_register_pane_checkout_form_validate($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
    //validation stuff
    return TRUE;
  }
  /**
   * Ouputs Review checkout pane.
   */
  function vts_register_pane_review($form, $form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
    // add some info to review pane
    return;
  }
  ```
- Go to admin/commerce/config/checkout and set it as disabled
- Install [Commerce Rules Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra), it adds the features you need :

> Rules conditions : Total product of type quantity comparison
>
> Rules actions : Change pane properties : Change visibility, page, weight of a pane

- Create a rule :

  - Event: Process checkout pane.
  - Conditions : user is anonymous ; subscription product quantity > 0.
  - Action : Change pane properties : enabled: true; move to checkout.

Comment: Great, I will try this. Do you have any suggestions for how to auto-approve the new account and log the user in before going to the next step?

Comment: @DaveBruns I edited the answer, this was a bit more tricky

Comment: thanks I appreciate you looking into this and providing more detail. Will this code redirect back to checkout after account creation? I also found something similar in https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra, (see Commerce Extra Login Page sub-module) but the redirect is not working for me.

Comment: The idea is Not to leave the checkout process. Register and log in immediately when going to review pane.Tested a couple of times only the above code. You may have to tune it a little bit, but this fully answers your question I believe. Let me know

Comment: Yes, of course. A little too much module testing, sorry. I've got your code in a module, but the submit function fails because $form_state is empty for some reason.

Comment: @DaveBruns I edited the answer and added a full version, assuming your module name is `vts_register`. This is working on my current test site. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @kojo! I appreciate the time you put into this. I will try it soon. If you have a moment, you may want to look at the login code in Commerce Extra, which is generally a good approach I think (adds a custom checkout page and pane).

Comment: @DaveBruns, as far as I understand, this is a different approach than the one you asked for: you have a one-page checkout. with the straight approach I purposed, you keep it. With Cm extra login, you break the checkout flow, the guy is redirected to login page, and then has to confirm email... Not good for sales ;-) For sure there might be several ways to achieve this, installing a login module and patch it for your needs... or declaring the register fields directly in the pane form instead of embedding the form...

Comment: I think the idea with cm extra is to add an extra page to checkout only when needed, but you're right, that is a different flow. I like your approach. Just need to try it now :)

Comment: Tried the new code, thanks @kojo. I can't get things to work right. $form_state is still empty when it hits the submit function. If I hard-code in values for $new_user, the user gets created but the order is not associated w/ the user & payment doesn't happen either. Have you been testing w/ a 1-page checkout that includes a payment method?

Comment: Indeed you're right, in a 1-page checkout, it is submitted too late. you should call `vts_register_pane_checkout_form_submit` in a ajax callback that you fire when the user leaves the last register field, after validating email with `valid_email_address($mail)` ... I'm very involved now in my projects so time's missing to write the latter part, but you're close to reach anyway

Comment: I understand. I've got other work I have to do as well but will try and revisit later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kojo’s excellent solution, I might add that I believe the correct username input field for normal Drupal install is located in:

```
'name' => $form_state['input']['name']
```

The module still redirects to the new user profile page, but I will be investigating the cause further today.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting also a setting in drupalcommerce for drupal 8.

```
/admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows/manage/default
```

Now there you will see

> Login or continue as guest

Click on gear icon, click and then uncheck `Allow guest checkout`.

That's all you need to do.

Comment: This answers the title of the question, but not the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i achieve to create the user_register_form commerce checkout pane :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info().
 */
function edw_commerce_dc_commerce_checkout_pane_info() {
  $panes['register'] = [
    'title' => t('Create an account'),
    'base' => 'edw_commerce_dc_register_pane',
    'name' => t('Authentication'),
    'file' => 'edw_commerce_dc.pane.inc',
    'page' => 'checkout',
    'weight' => -5,
  ];
  return $panes;
}

/*
 * Alter checkout form register pane
 */
function edw_commerce_dc_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  unset($form['register']['actions']);
  if(isset($form['register'])){
    $form_id = 'user_register_form';
    $hooks = array('form');
    $hooks[] = 'form_' . $form_id;
    drupal_alter($hooks, $form['register'], $form_state, $form_id);
  }
}

    /*
 * Add user_register_form to register pane
 */
function edw_commerce_dc_register_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    $pane_form = drupal_retrieve_form('user_register_form', $form_state);
    $pane_form['#tree'] = FALSE;
    return $pane_form;
  }
}

/**
 * checkout form submission callback.
 */
function edw_commerce_dc_register_pane_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  if (isset($form['register'])) {
    foreach ($form["register"]["#submit"] as $callback) {
      $callback($form['register'], $form_state);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * checkout form submission callback.
 */
function edw_commerce_dc_register_pane_checkout_form_validate($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  if (isset($form['register'])) {
    foreach ($form["register"]["#validate"] as $callback) {
      $callback($form['register'], $form_state);
    }
    if (!form_get_errors()) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```