# Register Drupal Commerce user before checkout completes

Tags: commerce

The default behavior for Drupal Commerce is that an anonymous user get's registered only after the checkout process completes and an order is paid in full. I am trying to create a new checkout rule to register an user just after he/she enters his/her e-mail address, but failing to find the right rule on admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/rules_sd/add/event.

I have modified my checkout flow, so that a user can enter his/her e-mail at the first step like shown in the screenshot:

[image: Checkout workflow]

Unfortunately, there is no rule something like "After entering an e-mail". Does anyone have a suggestion how to overcome this problem?

[image]

On /admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules it says:

> When a customer advances to the checkout completion page, rules
> reacting on the Completing the checkout process are evaluated. Default
> rules handle standard tasks like updating the order status, sending
> order e-mails, and creating accounts for anonymous users. You can edit
> these or add additional rules to customize your checkout workflow.

Does this mean I can't trigger any actions until checkout completes? Not very much convenient if so.

Edit: I've also found this somewhat similar discussion: [How to force account creation before commerce checkout is complete?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130407/how-to-force-account-creation-before-commerce-checkout-is-complete?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to do something *during* the checkout process, your best bet is to use a `hook_form_alter()` on the checkout forms and add your own submit handler. In this case you're looking at the `commerce_order_account_pane`. Remember that panes are fieldsets within a per-page form, so you'll want to look for the router page form and put your submit handler there.

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid your suggestion is out of my technical skills. Do you think I need to code a custom module? Mind giving some more details?